# How to alternate a manager's fields when focus changes

Tags: java, blackberry

I've been trying to have the field contents of a FlowFieldManager change to an informational snippet i.e. (***Contains Field1 and 34 more fields***), whenever the manager looses focus.

I constructed a FlowFieldManager thus:

```
new FlowFieldManager(FOCUSABLE);
```

And then I proceeded to set `FocusChangeListeners`, and even override both `onFocus` and `onUnfocus` methods, but nothing so far.

The desired behaviour is to have a manager with an extensive number of `LabelField`s signifying an item. The user can add as many items as they want into that manager. However, this can clutter the screen, so I want it such that when focus leaves the manager's visible area, it's contents change to a description of the number of fields, so that other managers on the screen can be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck overriding `nextFocus()` on your Manager:

```
protected int nextFocus(int direction, int axis);
    int next = super.nextFocus(directions, axis);
    if(next == -1) {
        //do stuff when you're losing focus
    }
    return next;
}
```